# R can't find existing header file GL/gl.h during install.packages("rgl")

Tags: r, c, linux, virtual-machine, rgl

I am having trouble installing 'rgl' on a Linux virtual machine (Ubuntu 18.04 - details at bottom). There are several related questions that are resolved by installing the required dependencies, however in my instance those dependency files exist and are not found by R when installing the R package "rgl".
The files in question are `GL/gl.h` and `GL/glu.h`

When running the standard `install.packages("rgl")`, R gives me this error in the installation report:

```
checking GL/gl.h usability... no
checking GL/gl.h presence... no
checking for GL/gl.h... no
checking GL/glu.h usability... no
checking GL/glu.h presence... no
checking for GL/glu.h... no
configure: error: missing required header GL/gl.h
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgl’
* removing ‘/opt/conda/lib/R/library/rgl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rgl’ had non-zero exit status
```

However, those files do exist in `/usr/include/GL/` as shown here:

```
root@[REDACTED]:/usr/include/GL# ls -la
total 1520
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root      6 Oct 27 23:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   4096 Oct 27 23:36 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  80393 Jun 12 01:21 gl.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 421419 Jun 12 01:21 glcorearb.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 848217 Jun 12 01:21 glext.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  17255 May 21  2016 glu.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3315 May 21  2016 glu_mangle.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  14578 Jun 12 01:21 glx.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  48752 Jun 12 01:21 glxext.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4706 Apr  3  2018 glxint.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2086 Apr  3  2018 glxmd.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  81112 Apr  3  2018 glxproto.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  11436 Apr  3  2018 glxtokens.h
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root     37 Sep 22 04:24 internal
```

I tried installing the package from the terminal using this commands:
`wget https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/rgl_0.100.54.tar.gz`
then
`R CMD INSTALL --configure-args="--with-gl-includes=/usr/include/GL/" rgl_0.100.54.tar.gz`
but that didn't work either.

TBH, I am not a Linux expert, so not sure if I'm close and making simple errors, or if there is something major happening under the hood to prevent this from working. I also tried quite a few things with the `PATH` variable in both R (using `Sys.setenv("PATH"="[LONG-PATH-HERE]")`) and in the terminal. When looking in the rgl package 'config' file, it seems like it is looking in the right place for the files, but I'm not sure how that file executes.

**OS version:**

```
LSB Version:    core-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:printing-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:security-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

**R Version:**

```
> R.version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu 
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          6.3                         
year           2020                        
month          02                          
day            29                          
svn rev        77875                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
nickname       Holding the Windsock
```

Thank you, stack overflow comrades.